# How to replace setLatestEventInfo

Tags: java, android, notifications

I'm looking for a way to replace `setLatestEventInfo` to make this code work. I know that `setLatestEventInfo` can't be used on API 23 and up and that there are several other questions which have already been answered but I don't get how to use notification builder in my case.

```
    Notification notification = new Notification(mNotificationIcon, mNotificationContentTitle, mNotificationWhen);
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MagicClock.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, mNotificationContentTitle, mNotificationContentText, contentIntent);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    mNotificationManager.notify(MagicClock.NOTIFICATION_ID_LOCATION, notification);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Notification notification;
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MagicClock.class);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = null;
if (currentapiVersion < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    notification = new Notification(mNotificationIcon, mNotificationContentText, mNotificationWhen);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, mNotificationContentTitle, mNotificationContentText, contentIntent);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    mNotificationManager.notify(MagicClock.NOTIFICATION_ID_LOCATION, notification);
} else {
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    notification = builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                    .setSmallIcon(mNotificationIcon).setTicker(mNotificationContentTitle).setWhen(mNotificationWhen)
                    .setAutoCancel(true).setContentTitle(mNotificationContentTitle)
                    .setContentText(text).build();
    mNotificationManager.notify(MagicClock.NOTIFICATION_ID_LOCATION, notification);
}
```

It might help you.

Comment: Now I get a different error 'The method setLatestEventInfo(MagicClock, String, String, PendingIntent) is undefined for the type Notification'.